# How to divide activity view into two display/screen

Tags: android, android-source, android-displaymanager

I am working on android automotive,

I need to divide activity view into two parts like half view in **primary display** and another half view in **RSE(Rear-Seat) display**.

May i know how to do?

which part/API of AOSP need to look?.